# Is there a DNAWeaver How-to guide?

Tags: phylogenetics

Recently I've been trying to use [DNA Weaver](https://github.com/Edinburgh-Genome-Foundry/DnaWeaver/blob/master/README.rst) for customized gene assembly design.
Although there is a web version that allows to perform some assembly examples, I've tried to replicate them with python code.

There is some documentation about it and it the developers have provided some examples within the documentation. However, I wonder if is there any other more extensive documentation with all the possible parameters / attributes for each function / objects.

An example of this is the definition of a "fixed size overhangs" during Gibson Assembly design, instead of using a Tm range for this task.  It has something to do with the "Overhang selector"

```
overhang_selector=dw.TmSegmentSelector(min_tm=55, max_tm=70),
```

But I have not found any information about what would be the code to run to replace the "TmSegmentSelector" for "FixedSizeSegmentSelector". However there are no clear instructions about this.

Other example would be how to specify a custom - genome or DNA sequence from which regions could be PCR amplified as part of the routine assembly.

And so on...

Does anybody could provide some light about this?

Thanks in advance!

Jorge.